# Convert Snapshot sequence to flv as3

Tags: flex4, red5

I am taking a serie of shapshot in Flex using :

```
var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot =  ImageSnapshot.captureImage(VisuModel.getInstance().mainApiContainer.mp);
var imageByteArray:ByteArray = imageSnap.data as ByteArray;
```

I would like to convert this sequence to a flash video file.
How can I achieve that using Red5 ?

All the best to ActionScript & Java developers !

Answer (score 0):

I used to following workflow :
1 -  Capture my screen in AS3

```
//this is just a constant
var snapshotDpi:Number=VisuModel.getInstance().snapshotDpi;
// Capture and convert to base64
var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot=
ImageSnapshot.captureImage(VisuModel.getInstance().mainApiContainer.mp,snapshotDpi);
var con:String=ImageSnapshot.encodeImageAsBase64(imageSnap)
// Save to img using amfphp
VisuModel.getInstance().gateway.call( "visumars.NewServices.SaveAsJPEG",
            new Responder(onResult_writeScript, onFault),con,imageName.getImageName())
```

2 - I then use mmpeg to save my jpeg sequence as flv